# Drush commands are not working in Xampp on Windows

Tags: drush

In Xampp 2 Drupal sites are there.one is drupal 7.0 and another one is drupal 8.8.7.
Drush version is 8.3.5, PHP version is 7.2.22 ,composer 1.9.2

When I try enabling module in Drupal 7.0

```
drush en serialization
```

> Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush      [error]from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
> The drush command 'en serialization' could not be executed.                                  [error]Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                 [error]Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
>
> - bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database.
>   In this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the
>   URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases`
>   for details.
> - connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may
>   have no access to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.
> - connect to the database through a cli command using the --defaults-extra-file
>   parameter to pass credentials through a tmp file. This method can break if other
>   credentials are specified in a ~/.my.cnf file in your home directory. You may have to
>   delete or rename the ~/.my.cnf file in your home directory.
>
>   ```
>   Drush was attempting to connect to:
>   Drupal version         :  7.0
>   Site URI               :  http://default
>   Database driver        :  mysql
>   Database hostname      :  localhost
>   Database port          :
>   Database username      :  root
>   Database name          :  drupal7
>   PHP configuration      :  C:\xampp\php\php.ini
>   Drush script           :  C:/Users/moonraft/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/drush/drus
>                             h/drush.php
>   Drush version          :  8.3.5
>   Drush temp directory   :  C:\Users\moonraft\AppData\Local\Temp
>   Drush configuration    :
>   Drush alias files      :
>   Drupal root            :  D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7
>   Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
>   Site path              :  sites/default
>   ```

Then if I try in Drupal 8.8.7

```
drush en serialization
```

> Could not load SQL class. There is a mismatch between your Drupal root and your PHP          [error]autoloading.
> This can happen if you mix Drupal 8 and Drupal 7.                                            [error]Please check that the location of Drush matches the Drupal core version you want Drush to    [error]talk to.
> Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush      [error]from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
> The drush command 'en serialization' could not be executed.                                  [error]Could not load SQL class. There is a mismatch between your Drupal root and       [error]
> your PHP autoloading.
> This can happen if you mix Drupal 8 and Drupal 7.                                [error]
> Please check that the location of Drush matches the Drupal core version you      [error]
> want Drush to talk to.
> Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                 [error]Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
>
> - bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database.
>   In this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the
>   URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases`
>   for details.
> - connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may
>   have no access to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.
> - connect to the database through a cli command using the --defaults-extra-file
>   parameter to pass credentials through a tmp file. This method can break if other
>   credentials are specified in a ~/.my.cnf file in your home directory. You may have to
>   delete or rename the ~/.my.cnf file in your home directory.
>
>   ```
>   Drush was attempting to connect to:
>   Drupal version         :  8.8.7
>   Site URI               :  http://default
>   PHP configuration      :  C:\xampp\php\php.ini
>   PHP OS                 :  WINNT
>   Drush script           :  C:/Users/moonraft/AppData/Roaming/Composer/vendor/drush/drus
>                            h/drush.php
>   Drush version          :  8.3.5
>   Drush temp directory   :  C:\Users\moonraft\AppData\Local\Temp
>   Drush configuration    :
>   Drush alias files      :
>   Drupal root            :  D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal8
>   Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
>   Site path              :  sites/default
>   Sync config path       :  D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal8/content/sync
>   ```

I am not sure what is the problem. Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Stop using XAMPP, use [DDEV](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead (requires Docker). Then you `ddev exec drush en serialization`. Alternatively look a bit around, for example https://www.drupal.org/node/594744. This has been asked on the internet many times before.

Comment: @leymannx but the problem with ddev or docker based applications is they can not run on nested virtualization technologies like Amazon workspace, Citrix workspace etc..,

Comment: If you have any insight on how to use them on nested virtualization can you please share it ?

Comment: @miststudent2011, buy a Linux workspace.

Comment: @miststudent2011 – I'd probably quit my job if I'd be forced to work with such a workspace. OS of my choice with admin rights is always part of the negotiation.